# In express, how do I insert new line to flow control part (non-evaluated code)?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How do I return a new line in Express when I'm *not* evaluating the string yet?

I know that `<%- %>` will not escape characters, but what if I'm just running a loop and want to add a new line before evaluating?

```
<% str = "" %>
<% for (var person in contacts) { %>
    <% str += person; %>
    <% for (subcategory in contacts[person]){ %>
        <% str += ", " + contacts[person][subcategory]; %>
    <% } %>
    <% str += "\n"; %>
<% } %> 
<h3><%= str %></h3>
```

My line `<% str += "\n"; %>` should simply add a new line to the string. But it ignores it (same with `\r`).

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing a HTML web page, you should print a tag that add a line  (`<BR>`)

Try this:

```
<% str = "<BR>" %>
```

Comment: I did `<% str += "<br>"; %>` but it added `<br>` literally to the string.

Comment: So you want print it in console with a new line in there?

Comment: How do you print the code or where??   If you print it with console.log  '\n' should be enough

Comment: I tried both of those (`\r\n`, `\r`). Not sure why it isn't working.  This is being resolved in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best thing I've found I could do is to replace `\n`, using `/foo/g` where `foo` is the text I want to replace.:

```
<% str = "" %>
<% for (var person in contacts) { %>
    <% str += person; %>
    <% for (subcategory in contacts[person]){ %>
        <% str += ", " + contacts[person][subcategory]; %>
    <% } %>
    <% str += "\n"; %>
<% } %> 
<% str = str.replace(/\n/g,'<br>'); %>
<h3><%- str; %></h3>
```

**Big note:** This assumes I want to replace *all* new line breaks.  That's not necessarily true. I still want just to create a new line after each `for (subcategory in...)` loop.

An option is to replace `str += "\n";` with say `str += "xxyyzz";` ...again, that assumes no other instance in my string that I want to leave in will be `xxyyzz`.